# Why my subscribe method doesn't use new state but only initial state?

Tags: reactjs

I want to calculate speed in my gps app, to do that I use states to save my current ans previous time, latitude and longitude.
I initialize the subscribe function in useEffect, however the previous state of time, lat and lon is always the same even though it should be updated several times. How can I make this work without using localStorage to hold these values?

```
 const [lat, setLat] = useState(51.55);
    const [lon, setLon] = useState(0);
    const [prevLat, setPrevLat] = useState(0);
    const [prevLon, setPrevLon] = useState(0);
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());
    const [prevTime, setPrevTime] = useState(new Date());

    useEffect(() => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

            setTime(resp.timestamp);
            setLat(resp.coords.latitude)
            setLon(resp.coords.longitude)

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting location', error);
        })

        const onSuccess = () => {
            console.log('success')
        }
        const onError = () => {
            console.log('error')
        }

        let watch = Geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });

        watch.subscribe((data) => {
            if (data && data.coords && data.coords.latitude && data.coords.longitude) {
                setPrevLat(lat);
                setPrevLon(lon);
                setPrevTime(time);
                setLat(data.coords.latitude);
                setLon(data.coords.longitude);
                setTime(data.timestamp);

                //calculate speed
                console.log(calculateSpeed(prevTime, prevLat, prevLon, data.timestamp, data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude));
            } else {
                alert(data.message, ' ', data.code)
            }

        });
    }, [])
```

In other words 4th, 5th and 6th arguments of calculateSpeed are proper values, but prevTime, prevLon and prevLat are still accordingly: date when the app started to run, 0, 0

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic functional programming issue that you have to watch out for with closures.

What's happening is the following:

1. Your `useEffect` is getting called only on the first render, since you have `[]` as the dependencies.
2. It initializes `watch.subscribe` with an anonymous function and creates a *closure*! This closure has access to parent scope variables, but it takes a snapshot of those variables at the time that the closure is created!
3. When your `subscribe` callback is triggered, it still operates using the same variables it had when the closure was created. This is a ["stale closure"](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

So, how can you fix this?

One strategy is to unsubscribe your subscribe callback and re-subscribe with a fresh closure whenever the state changes by passing the state variables to the `useEffect` dependencies (but this will depend on the `Geolocation` API). See the link above for other options.

You can also easily address the issue by using a class component with a class method to replace the function in the `watch.subscribe` call. Class methods don't have the same stale closure problems that pure functional React hooks do.

I can't give a concrete solution to your problem because the design changes may change the desired behaviour, but I hope this gives you an understanding of the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this might be an interesting read, i have tried setting up dependencies in my useEffect, however with the limited options I have (using Ionic here) i have no means to unsubscribe from the watch and thus create new instances of watch every time dependencies change. 

I'll dive deeper into the geolocation service docs im using and maybe find a way to unsubscribe, otherwise I'll have to use different solutions presented in the article :)

Comment: Nice! If you're really struggling to find a solution given your constraints, try reverting to a class component (blasphemy, I know). It will help and still make your code easily to reason about.

Comment: I think it would probably be easier / less time consuming to just use localStorage to save those variables, but I want to try other solutions first just for the sake of learning

Comment: If you don't need to re-render on the state variable changes, consider `useRef` instead. It has stable identity that would work with your existing implementation.